# Python - How to use multi threading with queue when you don't know how many times you need to

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I am using python and I am using it to read a text file and then am processing the data every x amount of lines.

```
for line in open('verybigfile.txt'):
    process_data(line)
```

Here is the function

```
def process_data(line):
        if line == '***RECORD END***':
        x = threading.Thread(target=processList, args=(big_list,))
        x.start()

        print('starting thread')
        return

    big_list.append(line)
```

I am trying to make it so there is a maximum of 10 threads running at a single moment. All the articles and research I have read show examples of multithreading with a queue when you already have a predefined amount of jobs you need to do.

Can someone help me figure out how I can have 10 workers/threads continuously run as the program continues to add the the list of jobs to do?

Comment: use `Pool(10)` and will run always max 10 processes even if you add data for 100 processes.

Comment: see `Pool` in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I don't quite understand the meaning, do you want to assume that there are 100 things, and the processing process is up to 10 threads?